# How can I use v-model in base component with vee-validate?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vee-validate

I want to validate using vue vee-validate and baseinputs. But I cannot use v-model where I call the component.

my TextInput Component.

```
<template>
  <div
    class="TextInput"
    :class="{ 'has-error': !!errorMessage, success: meta.valid }"
  >
    <label :for="name">{{ label }}</label>
    <input
      :name="name"
      :id="name"
      :type="type"
      :value="inputValue"
      :placeholder="placeholder"
      @input="handleChange"
      @blur="handleBlur"
    />

    <p class="help-message" v-show="errorMessage || meta.valid">
      {{ errorMessage || successMessage }}
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { useField } from "vee-validate";

export default {
  props: {
    type: {
      type: String,
      default: "text",
    },
    value: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    label: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    successMessage: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
    placeholder: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
  },
  setup(props) { 
    const {
      value: inputValue,
      errorMessage,
      handleBlur,
      handleChange,
      meta,
    } = useField(props.name, undefined, {
      initialValue: props.value,
    });

    return {
      handleChange,
      handleBlur,
      errorMessage,
      inputValue,
      meta,
    };
  },
};
```

App.vue file where I call the component

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ test }}
    <Form
      @submit="onSubmit"
      :validation-schema="schema"
      @invalid-submit="onInvalidSubmit"
    >
      <TextInput
        name="name"
        type="text"
        label="Full Name"
        placeholder="Your Name"
        success-message="Nice to meet you!"
        v-model="test"
      />
    
      <button class="submit-btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </Form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from "vue";
import { Form } from "vee-validate";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import TextInput from "./components/TextInput.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    TextInput,
    Form,
  },
  setup() {
    const test = ref("asda");
    function onSubmit(values) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
    }

    function onInvalidSubmit() {
      const submitBtn = document.querySelector(".submit-btn");
      submitBtn.classList.add("invalid");
      setTimeout(() => {
        submitBtn.classList.remove("invalid");
      }, 1000);
    }
    const schema = Yup.object().shape({
      name: Yup.string().required(),
      email: Yup.string().email().required(),
      password: Yup.string().min(6).required(),
      confirm_password: Yup.string()
        .required()
        .oneOf([Yup.ref("password")], "Passwords do not match"),
    });

    return {
      onSubmit,
      schema,
      onInvalidSubmit,
      test,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

where I wrote in `v-model ="test"` doesn't work. I tried to send it with emit but I couldn't.

So, in summary, let the component I validate perform the validation process, but I can use the v-model where I call the component.